# ServiceNOW and KB article with MS Chatbot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

We want to leverage the ServiceNOW Knowledge Base/articles to fetch articles from a customer ServiceNOW production instance through a Chatbot.

As ServiceNOW administrators, how do you propose we work to get this integration completed? I was looking at the community for expert advise, to help us arrive to a conclusion on how to do this efficiently with minimum stress to ServiceNOW.

We thought we had two options:-

1. Index articles and store it in cloud/local database and query
   cloud/local database when user queries for information. Refresh
   cloud/local database index weekly. (I think this is preferred)
2. Use the knowledge API directly to hit ServiceNOW. In that case,
   every user searches will land up in ServiceNOW.